# Kivy Image is not loading showing white square on the Phone screen corner

Tags: python, android, image, kivy, buildozer

I made a simple application with Kivy in Python which just displays up a Png Image. But when I Build an APK with the buildozer and run it on the Mobile phone it shows me a black screen with a white box square in the bottom left corner. I visited forums with similar questions but I didn't found anything clearly mentioned about this problem. Kindly guide me, what is wrong with my APK?

here's the code.

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image 

  class MyApp(App): 

        def build(self): 


            return Image(source =r'C:\Users\amitn\Music\apk luci stuff\luci2.png',allow_stretch=True) 

    MyApp().run()
```

When I build Apk of this python file with Buildozer, it gave me the result as in the below Image.

[This is what my phone screen shows up when I run the app after the installation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jMPT.jpg)

Comment: Do you think that there is a `C:\Users\amitn\Music\apk luci stuff\luci2.png` in your phone?

Comment: No. it's the path of the image in the pc. is there any problem in the path.

Comment: The problem is that it *doesn't exist* in the phone ;o)

Comment: But i am building a apk with buildozer so how will a apk need a path for Image in the phone to load.

Comment: The apk runs on the phone. There (on the phone), when it runs, it tries to find the `C:\Users\amitn\Music\apk luci stuff\luci2.png`. It doesn't. So, it displays an empty square.. What part you of this you don't understand?

Comment: but  as we see other apk on the playstore or from any other source.. when we download install them no image is downloded with it.. then when we run it how does the image is loded over there. Are you getting what i am trying to say.

Comment: I do, but do you? The app must bundle its images *inside* the apk. How do you expect that the app will find the image from your drive? You have to read more about [packaging an app with Buildozer](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specifications.html)..:o)  There is a `source.dir` in the Buildozer `spec` that you can use to include a folder with assets (images, fonts etc) in your apk.